# Какое css свойство поможет, чтобы бекгроунд закрасил только текст

Tags: html, css

Есть список li, дал padding и бекгроунд, а он растянулся на всю ширину экран.
Какое css свойство поможет чтобы бекгроунд закрасил только текст, и не растягивался, кроме width

Answer (score 2):

`li` - это блок, и конечно он будет весь закрашиваться в цвет. Оберните текст внутри `li`, например, в тег `<p>` или `<span>`,

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <p>Ваш текст</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <p>Ваш текст</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

и задайте ему свойства, которые приписывали `li`:

```
li p {
    background-color: #ваш цвет;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте обертку div.

```
<div>
   <p>Text</p>
</div>
```